# jQuery get HTML-file with ajax and run JS code from main-site

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a basic HTML-file, which serves as wrapper. In this file, I have somethingl ike this:

```
<div class="myBtn">Click me</div>
<div class="myContainer"></div>
```

After clicking the button, I want to load the stuff from a given HTML-resource:

```
function showContent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "mySnippet.html",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('.myContainer').append(data);
            $('.myContainer').fadeIn();
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    })
}
```

Now the main problem: The content-site looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    My headline
    <button type="button" class="close"
            data-target="copyright-wrap"
            data-dismiss="panel">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The button for instance is linked like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.close').click(function() {
       console.log('should trigger, but it does not');
    }
});
```

When I try to handle click-events on the close-button, it isn't working at all. I tried it with `document(ready)` as well as `window(load)`.

Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: did you - in any kind - link your button to the function you try to call? If so: could we see this?

Comment: I'm Sorry @Niklas, I edited the post. Yes, it is linked. I just forgot to add that snippet to my question. Thank you.

Comment: So this "close" button is what mySnippet.html contains and you appending the whole snippet via ajax call? Where do you bind the event? In the snippet or main document? 'cause if it's main document then bind onclick event inside ajax success, right after append....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many workaround on this one, but my favourite is to bind click events to all DOM elements using that selector the current one and features elements.

eg :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').on("click",".close",function() {
       console.log('should trigger, but it does not');
    }
});
```

So all elements targeted with **.close** selector will bind that event and future ones created dynamically, as the load event is fired only once the page is loaded.

Comment: Missing comma "," after `".close"` ?

Comment: Works like a charme. Just add the "," after ".close"func... - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.ready()` event delegation from `document`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on("click", ".close", function() {
       console.log('should trigger, but it does not');
    });
});
```